# How do I compile a module in User Mode Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module, user-mode-linux

Having a tough time compiling a module for User Mode Linux. I just need a basic way to compile a very basic module in user mode linux and cannot seem to get it to work. I checked out the how-to on sourceforge for UML but had no luck. Anyone have a working example of what it takes?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any specific error while compiling module?

You can compile module as for normal kernel, but you must to point to the right kernel headers (UML's one)

Comment: It's the headers that seem to be the issue. Is there a way to compile the module before booting into the UML? Can I compile it from my host using the UML headers or do I have to be in UML? I have a source tree and make the UML instance against that. I had been trying to compile inside of the UML instance but in /lib/modules there are no files and the makefile I'm using tries to pull from /lib/modules/VERSION/build. Do you have any resources for how to compile a UML module? Any way to compile in the host fs using the UML headers?

Comment: I've tried so many different methods today and have gotten many different errors -- I really haven't found a path that's promising for this and can't get it to compile